# Finding sum of values in a JTable column

Tags: java, swing

I want to find sum of values in column in JTable.I have retrieved values from JTable using `getvalueAt` method, but it's not finding sum of values at last. This is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    for(int i = 0; i <model1.getRowCount(); i++) {
        int total =0;
        int Amount =Integer.parseInt(model1.getValueAt(i,3)+"");
        total +=Amount;
        System.out.println(total);
     }
}
```

My current output is getting like this:

```
10 // values in column
20
30
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring `total` within your `for` loop, so it gets initialized to `0` at each iteration.

Declare it before your `for` loop.